# PHP can not upload rar file

Tags: php, file-upload, rar

I need your help.
I'm trying to upload a RAR archive and I have not any good result, but any other file I can upload.
I thought that my php script was a broken, but when I've tryed easiest script, like this http://pastebin.com/GEHkgQz2 which just displays variable $_FILES, I've saw this: 
Array ( [filename] => Array ( [name] => test.rar [type] => [tmp_name] => [error] => 1 [size] => 0 ) ) 
Why I've got this error? What that means? What I must to do to upload this file?
Sorry for my english - I've used to read, but not to write =)

Comment: Please check your upload_max_filesize in your php.ini and compare it with the size of your rar file

Comment: Please attempt some further investigation before posting to SO. For your problem, check out [PHP File Upload Errors Explained](http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.errors.php)

Answer (score 0):

The uploaded file exceeds the upload_max_filesize directive in php.ini

Answer (score 0):

Confirm that you coded the upload function to accept .rar extensions...